# SQL to get latest version of modules (max ID) from DB?

Tags: sql-server, max, subset

**Goal**: I am trying to get the latest version of each "module"(e.g. API, Angular Site, Admin, etc) for production and release (on primary and dr server) from a database that has records for Deployments

**Problem**: My query seems to return the latest for all except one particular module
It is returning the latest on production (version 46.14) for everything except that one module (which is returning version 45.7)

I've been going at this for hours

**What I've tried**:

I've tried changing the order in the Group by, as well as in the Order by

I've tried removing items from group by and order by

I've tried starting with a smallest part of the query and adding piece by piece from scratch

I've looked up information about max, group by, and order by

It seems to return the correct version when I don't have the Location field. However, Location is a new necessary field, so I can't get rid of that.

I'm not sure which direction to go at this point?

**Key**:

Env = Environment (e.g. Prod or Rel)
Location (Main or DR)
Ver = Version (e.g. 45.7 or 46.14)

Using SQL Server

**SQL**:

```
select m.Name as Module, l.Name as Location, e.Name as Env, v.Name as Ver, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16), d.OccurredOn, 120) 
from deployment d 
inner join module m on d.ModuleID = m.ID
inner join Location l on d.LocationID = l.ID 
inner join Environment e on d.EnvironmentID = e.ID
inner join versionset v on d.VersionSetID = v.ID
where d.ID in ( 
select max(d.ID) 
    from deployment d
    inner join module m on d.moduleID = m.ID
    where d.OccurredOn > '2019-01-01' and m.SuiteID = 3 and m.ID <> 12 and m.ID <> 19 AND d.EnvironmentID <> 4
    group by d.LocationID, d.EnvironmentID, d.ModuleID  
    )
    order by d.LocationID, d.EnvironmentID, d.ModuleID
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to return the correct version when I don't have the Location field.

Looks like `d.LocationID` is `NULL` for that particular record, or value that is stored in `d.locationID` doesn't exsist in `Location` table. The later should not happen if `d.LocationID` is `FOREIGN KEY` referencing `Location.ID`. Instead of `INNER JOIN` use `LEFT JOIN` in

```
inner join Location l on d.LocationID = l.ID
```

like this

```
left join Location l on d.LocationID = l.ID
```

In this case `l.Name` in `SELECT` will be empty.

You can leave `d.LocationID` in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It may be easier for the OP to understand if you use left join in your code sample rather than inner join. A field with a foreign key field actually allows null... if the column definition allows it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for correction. I've changed the answer.

Comment: Hi. After doing investigating, YES that field IS null for the most recent row, but not for an older row(the one its showing). If I update it manually it will show. But Im wondering if I can adjust my SELECT query to still include it even though its NULL? I tried the Left join but it got a lot of other NULL rows, and it actually looks worse now because instead of 1 incorrect row, a lot of them are incorrect (pulling older versions for many of the modules)

Comment: @angleUr Hi. You could add more conditions to `where` clause. This condition should do: `d.locationID IS NOT NULL OR d.LocationID IS NULL AND [module_version_equals_45.7]`. `[module_version_equals_45.7]` must not be determined using `Location` table because there's no record to determine the module version. However, I think this is not a good solution, although it will work, because the error is in the field `d.LocationID`. Maybe you could further concentrate on it and fix that issue.